# C++ syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I have the following line of code in my program -

```
typedef GROUP ACE_SOCK_GROUP;
```

That gives the following warnings and errors -

*Warning    181 warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared*

*Error  182 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'*

*Error  183 error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'*

The definition of GROUP is given in another file that is included by my program as -

```
typedef unsigned int             GROUP;
```

- What does 'constant' here refer to?
- What could be causing the error?
- What is the warning indicating

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and found the definition of GROUP using the F12 function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct.

You're forgetting to include the file where `GROUP` is defined.

You can try a simple test to confirm this is the issue:

```
typedef unsigned int             GROUP;
typedef GROUP ACE_SOCK_GROUP;
```

If this compiles, and it will, that means that the previous definition of `GROUP` is not seen. You need to include the file with the definition before defining `ACE_SOCK_GROUP`.

Comment: I am trying to build an existing solution. I have verified that the solution works perfectly fine and no code changes are required to get it to build, just environment/property setting changes.

Other than the linkage between this file and the one containing the definition of GROUP, what other factors can I look at to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala there could be preprocessor definitions that exclude the definition of `GROUP` from the build. You can check if the typedef is between `#ifdef/#endif` or `#if defined/#endif` macros. Have you tried the test I suggested?